# I want to select a MySql table row's content partially

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I use this code:

```
id = Database.geti("menu", "id", "title LIKE '%" + title + "%'");
```

What generates this SQL query:

```
SELECT id FROM menu WHERE title LIKE '%Shop / Main   Page 4 of 7%';
```

**My goal is to select the row with the title "Shop / Main"** Im new to SQL, please help me. Thanks in advance.

*Update*
Not a nice solution but I used this:

title = title.split("‎‎    ")[0];

Comment: First: get rid of concatenation, read the documentation about the [prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and use bind variables. Second: pass the text you need without that pages part. Third: compare with equality (`=`) for exact match.

Comment: `"SELECT id FROM menu WHERE title = 'Shop / Main';"`. The `LIKE` statement is used more for search type queries. Unless of course the title actually contains more than `Shop / Main`. :/ Also Use prepared statements